# How to get the data in MM/dd/yyyy format in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Login authentication on my website is based on three parameters of which one is date of birth. A `DatePicker` is provided to the user to select the Date. The format in which the date is saved in Database is MM/dd/yyyy.

When is check for the authentication the Linq query is not returning any result as the record in Database is in MM/dd/yyyy and the value passed from the view to the controller is in dd/mm/yyyy.Hence im not getting any output.

Below is my code of what I'm doing in controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginTable log)
        {
            var login = from a in db.LoginTables
                        where a.DOB== log.DOB
                        select a;
        }
```

Also I have tried

```
var login = from a in db.LoginTables
                            where a.DOB== log.DOB.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                            select a;
```

but its giving error (No Overload method 'ToString()' takes 1 argument)

What can i do?

Comment: Are you storing the date in the database as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because the LINQ is translated into SQL syntax and there is no equivalent of `ToString` in SQL.

Given that `log` is a parameter to your method why not simply have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginTable log)
{
    string DOBString = log.DOB.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

    var login = from a in db.LoginTables
                where a.DOB == DOBString
                select a;
}
```

Comment: Definition of DOB column in Database is DateTime.
Tried using DateTime DOBString as well as String DOBString.
Same issue (NO Overload for method 'ToString()' takes 1 Arguement)